# Ajax requests on multiple domains and keep PHP sessions alive in each domains

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, cross-domain

I have developped a website in PHP / Ajax / MySQL.

The website is working mainly with domain A, and for some reasons I have to send AJAX request to domain B.

And I need to keep the two differents sessions alive on the two domains.
But On the domain B, the session is regenerated at each request.

I think that I have to configure Ajax resquest and PHP response to manage this situation.

I have already try to add crossDomain param to my AJAX request, and I have also add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " to my PHP response,  but no effect...

After several hours of researchs, I still not find the rights parameters.

I am using Jquery to send AJAX request, and PHP 7.3 for send responses.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: ... and? You're not describing a problem, nor asking a question.

Comment: The problem is that at each request on the B domain, the PHP session is not saved, it is regenerated at each request.